# Updating matching columns from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, updating

We have two tables:

- table 1: `users` (`username`, `password`)
- table 2: `userinfo` (`office`, `address`, `company`)

The username is the same as the office name. I have created a form to add new users, and everything works great.

I have another form to update user.. I can get everything to work, except the username/office.

How would I go about updating the username/office

here is my code (obviously it is wrong, as it does nothing) This has been driving me crazy all day. Any pointers would be appreciated:

```
    $query2 =   'UPDATE users.UserName JOIN userinfo.Office ON users.UserName = userinfo.Office SET users.UserName = ?,userinfo.Office = ? WHERE users.UserName = ?';
    $parameters2 = array($_POST['UserName'],$_POST['Office']);
    $statement2  = $db->prepare($query2);
    $statement2->execute($parameters2);
```

Comment: Can a user have more than one office?  I am just wondering why this information is in two different tables if there is not a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship between users and userinfo.

Comment: @MikeBrant No, it is one user per office. The username is the same as office name (per client request).

Comment: So why is this not all just a single table?

Comment: @MikeBrant That is not the concern. The issue at hand is ability to update username/office. users table holds only username/password/and another column. userinfo: is all office, company, products associated with client.. etc.. This was not a database I designed. I was hired to implement user account pages, etc... and admin page. So, question is, where is the error in my syntax

Comment: Your query has 3 `?` placeholders, but `$parameters2` only has 2 elements. What is supposed to be used for the third placeholder?

Comment: Why do you have separate `Username` and `Office` fields in the form if these are the same?

Comment: Just asking as if you have the ability to make it a single table, you eliminate the need to update across a join to being with.

Comment: @MikeBrant Well, that code definitely changed the username and office, but did so for everyone in the database.

Comment: @jelliott Did you mean this as as comment to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem has improper syntax  There should not be any field names before the `SET` clause. On update you just indicate the table names to be operated on in this portion of the query.  Try this:

```
UPDATE users
JOIN userinfo
  ON users.UserName = userinfo.Office
SET
  users.UserName = ?,
  userinfo.Office = ?
WHERE users.UserName = ?
```

I also don't understand why you would have two different POST variables for username and office if these are to be the the same value.  So, I am assuming that one represents the current value and the other, the value to be updated to.   If this is the case, you would need to bind your parameters like this:

```
// change these two lines as necessary
$old_name = $_POST['Office'];
$new_name = $_POST['UserName'];
// execute query
$query2 = '...'; // query noted above
$parameters2 = array($new_name, $new_name, $old_name);
$statement2  = $db->prepare($query2);
$statement2->execute($parameters2);
```

Comment: Well, that code definitely changed the username and office, but did so for everyone in the database.

Comment: @jelliott It should only touch those rows where `user.UserName = $old_name`.  What does your `$old_name` value hold in this case?